# std_srvs not found in ros2

Tags: ros, ros2, c++, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to include a service from std_srvs like I do in the beginning in my C++ Code:

`#include "std_srvs/srv/SetBool.hpp"`

in my CMakeLists.txt I included the following lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(test_node)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_srvs REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

add_executable(testing src/testing.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(testing
    rclcpp
    std_srvs
)

install(TARGETS testing 
    EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
    DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
 )

ament_package()
```

but when I run `colcon build` I alwas get the error:

```
fatal error: example_interfaces/srv/SetBool.hpp: No such file or directory
4 | #include "std_srvs/srv/SetBool.hpp"
```

What I am doing wrong here? How can I include this service for my node ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405494/std_srvs-not-found-in-ros2/) by [meikse](https://answers.ros.org/users/113590/meikse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did find the solution:

the `#inlcude` line needs to be changed to

```
#inlcude "std_srvs/srv/set_bool.hpp"
```

I found the solution actually here

edit: I did all the [tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials.html) before but could not find that necessary information for including ros libs properly. Sorry for asking, but it took me more than a day to figure that out and asking here was my last hope. Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052476/ros2-colcon-build-could-not-generate-hpp-files)

---

Originally posted by [meikse](https://answers.ros.org/users/113590/meikse/) with karma: 16 on 2022-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0